Asymptotic bound
How can this relation : $$ T(n)=4^n + 12 \cdot \sum^{n-2}_{i=1}{T(i)} $$
$$ T(1) = 1 $$
be evaluated to asysmtotic bound (Big O notation)?
It could be easy if the upper bound of the sum were n-1, but it is not.

You can always add extra non-negative terms on the RHS, if that helps. Whether the bound will be asymptotically tight is a different question. But nevertheless, you would get an upper bound.

$T(1)$ should be $O(1)$ to be consistent with the recurrence.

How is adding extra terms helpful here?

$T(n) \le 4^n + 12\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} T(i)$, then, as per your claim, it is comparably easy to solve!
